# React native cost of defining inline styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use inline styles absolutely everywhere in react native. I find it a much more convenient way of styling things.

```
<View
    style={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        flexShrink: 1,
        paddingRight: 16,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    }}
    />
```

I haven't seen any performance issues and it's quite a large app. What is the performance cost of doing this vs StyleSheet? How can I measure this performance impact?